# Why does a too small container cause a child to clip to its own bounds?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

For alignment purposes, I have a control which renders a button outside of it's own bounds. This seems to work perfectly in most cases, but it produces undesired output in cases where the size of the control plus its margins exceeds the outline of its container.

Below is an example where the red grid represents the control and the blue rectangle is the button. The blue rectangle renders correctly when the outer grid is sufficiently big (`Width="300"`), but not when the outer grid is too small to contain the red grid and its margin. The blue rectangle will then get clipped to the bounds for the red grid.

This seems to be a bug. I would expect the blue rectangle to be clipped according to the bounds of the outer grid and the right margin of the red grid, but being clipped to the bounds of the red rectangle makes no sense to me. What is the best approach for working around this? I could set the right margin of the red grid to a sufficiently large negative number and set `ClipToBounds="True"` on the outer grid, but I was hoping that there would be a better solution.

```
<Grid Width="300">
    <Grid Margin="50" Background="Red" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Margin="-20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="50" Height="50" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image: example 1]

```
<Grid Width="299">
    <Grid Margin="50" Background="Red" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Margin="-20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="50" Height="50" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image: example 2]

Comment: Wow, that is interesting. Looks like a bug to me too. Did you post it to Microsoft Connect?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, thank you for the suggestion. I posted it to Microsoft Connect ([here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1007142)) today.